# Reading and writing to text file adds invalid characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-io

Working on reading from, parsing data, and then overwriting new data to a text file. My problem is, writing to the file is adding invalid characters to the beginning before adding what I want it to. The error I get is:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\x00\x0045.5'
```

`45.5, 5.0` is the data I am trying to write to the file and each `\x00` represents an invalid character added during the writing to the file process. Normally there's like 10-15 added each iteration. I can manually go into the text file and delete them, but what's the fun in that?

This is my code, and the try/except is what I added to try to fix the problem-

```
def __init__(self, power):
    self.name = "Dr. Strange"
    self.CloakOfLevitation = "I like Dr. Strange"
    self.EyeOfAgamotto = InfinityStones.TimeStone(5000 + power, self.name)
    self.win = False
    self.length = randint(2, 100)

    stats = open("Stats.txt", 'r+', encoding = 'utf-8')
    data = stats.read()

    try:
        avg, tries = data.split(sep = ',')
        avg = float(avg)
        tries = float(tries)
    except ValueError:
        stats.truncate(0)
        stats.write(data[1:])
        sleep(5)
        stats.close()
        self.__init__(power)

    self.new_avg = avg + (self.length - avg) / tries
    stats.truncate(0)
    stats.write(str(self.new_avg) + ',' + str((tries + 1)))
    stats.close()
```

The majority of this code involves recursion, `self.length` determines how long the recursion will last, `power` is just a number and isn't important for this part. `sleep(5)` is in there so I can stop the program while it's running before it blows up my computer. Each time it writes data to the file, it adds invalid characters (represented as `\x00` in the error output). `avg` is supposed to be the average number of 'deaths' before the recursion is done, and `tries` is the number of times the program has been run.

The idea of the `try/except` block is to attempt to convert the data in the file to integers so math can be done with them, and if it can't turn it into a character, attempt to drop the first character in the text file (supposedly an invalid character) and then try again (rerun `__init__`). Currently it just kinda blows up.

I saw stuff about encoding, and tried that, but it didn't change anything. Invalid characters are still being added. I have `truncate(0)` there to wipe the file so that I'm overwriting the file instead of appending data.

Comment: Two side notes: (1) `tries` is presumably a number of tries; as such, it must be an `int`, not a `float`. (2) A cleaner way to rewrite the file contents is to read from the file, close it, then open for writing, and write into it.

Comment: Also, recursively calling `__init__` from inside `__init__` is very weird. If you want to loop until success, use a `while` loop, don't simulate one with recursion. Notice that with your recursive calling, when you finally succeed, you're going to have a whole stack of functions that all have separate handles for the same disk file, and that all try to `truncate`, `write`, and `close` their file, and I can't imagine a scenario where that would be a good thing. Plus, that will include the one(s) that already `close`d the file…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to step back in the file anytime you do a truncate. So where you do this `stats.truncate(0)` add `stats.seek(0)` after

Comment: Thank you! This works, but why is it necessary? There's no characters in the file at that point, shouldn't the current position therefore be at the beginning of the file?

Comment: @elkshadow5 the docs say that “The current file position is not changed” That’s the clue that lead me to see you needed to manually seek instead. I’m not sure entirely why it’s not part of the operation but there must be some use case.